# How to recreate the "Debug" configuration for xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration

I accidentally deleted the "Debug" configuration of one xcode project.
Now when i try to create a new one i can only duplicate the release configuration. (See the screenshot)

Is there any way to recreate the standard debug configuration?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Restore from your Git repository or TimeMachine backup.

Comment: Click on Duplicate "Release" Configuration & rename "Release" to "Debug" by double clicking on text. Now goto top iOS Device & simulator click on project name -> Click Edit scheme -> Under Configuration now select Debug

Comment: duplicating the release configuration i will create a new "release" configuration that is totally different from the Debug.